# How is NULL terminated?

Tags: c, string, null, null-terminated

Looking to the declaration below

```
const char REASON_POR = "POR";
```

the question is, why will `REASON_POR` be `NULL` terminated ?

Comment: What do you mean? That's how C works. String literals are null terminated.

Comment: C is very confusing. Note that `NULL` (capitals) is a macro that's used as a *pointer* constant. You however are after something entirely different, namely a *character* with numeric value zero. It's usually spelled `'\0'`, though just `0` would also work, and sometimes the symbol "NUL" (one 'L') is used, too. That is, strings are "zero-terminated" or "null-terminated" ("null" being an alternative word for "zero"), or maybe NUL-terminated, but never the thing you said.

Comment: OMG `"POR"` is type of `char *`, not `char`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
const char REASON_POR = "POR";
```

is **wrong**, since `REASON_POR` is a constant of type `char`, and you are assigning a string to it, while you should just assign a character, e.g. 'P'.

Strictly speaking, there is no assigning of a string in C, but rather one can only assign the pointer with the address of a char (in case of the string).<sup>*</sup>

Assigning a pointer (of the string) to a `char` invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

---

*<sub>There is only one exception from this rule - initialisation of the char table (or any other table or structure in general): `char str[]="foo";` where actual string is being copied.</sub>

Comment: My brain made me think there was a '*' after char lol. Good catch

Comment: You cannot assign the string. There is no string assignment in the C language. You can only assign the pointer with the address of a char (in case of the string). There is only one exception from this rule - initialisation of the char table (or any other table or structure in general): `char str[]="asasas";` where actual string is being copied.

Comment: Not string literals - initialisation of the char arrays which makes a huge difference

Answer (score 0):

String literals are defined by the language to have a nul byte at the end. This is why `sizeof("POR")` equals `4`, not `3`. When the compiler generates the string literal into the output binary, it arranges for the nul byte to be present.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess why strings in C are null terminated, it could be because Dennis Ritchie thought it would be a good idea to be able to identify the end of a string. Many convenience functions work using this feature, such as strlen